# Passing pre-processor flags that contain special characters [c++17, g++]

Tags: c++, g++, preprocessor

I am trying to assign a value to a `const char*` by using a pre-processor flag in the following way.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define ST(A...) #A
#define STR(A) ST(A)

const char* output = STR(FLAG);

int main() {
    std::cout << output;
}
```

This approach works well, unless FLAG contains some special characters. When I attempt to build the above with

```
g++ .\Main.cpp -std=c++17 -DFLAG="a,b!c)d}e-f"
```

I get this in the error log. It doesn't like the special characters.

```
<command-line>: error: expected ',' or ';' before 'd'
.\Main.cpp:4:19: note: in definition of macro 'STR'
    4 | #define STR(A) ST(A)
      |                   ^
.\Main.cpp:6:26: note: in expansion of macro 'FLAG'
    6 | const char* output = STR(FLAG);
      |                          ^~~~
<command-line>: error: expected declaration before '}' token
.\Main.cpp:4:19: note: in definition of macro 'STR'
    4 | #define STR(A) ST(A)
    6 | const char* output = STR(FLAG);
      |                          ^~~~
<command-line>: error: 'e' does not name a type
.\Main.cpp:4:19: note: in definition of macro 'STR'
    4 | #define STR(A) ST(A)
      |                   ^
.\Main.cpp:6:26: note: in expansion of macro 'FLAG'
    6 | const char* output = STR(FLAG);
      |
```

The desired output of the program would be `a,b!c)d}e-f`.

Is there any (sane) way to obtain this functionality using pre-processor flags, or something similar?

Comment: If you do `#define FLAG a,b!c)d}e-f` you will get the same error. `(A...)` is a GNU extension, I think prefer `ST(...) #__VA_ARGS__`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use stringification macros when `FLAG` is a string:

```
-std=c++17 -DFLAG="\"a,b!c)d}e-f\""
```

[Live Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/ax74EhErP)

Comment: Thank you. I had tried this earlier on g++ 10.3 built by MSYS2 with no success. Changing compilers resolved the issue.

Comment: @Ryan apart from the `-std=c++17` it should work with any version https://godbolt.org/z/onWYa618o